# Filter posts by category in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I have a folder of markdown files each with a number of key/values. I need to filter all of the markdown files in the `_faq` folder by the key `faq_category`.

I have tried:

```
 {% assign post = site.faqs | where: "faq_category", name-of-category %}
  <ul>
  <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
  </ul>
```

However, this is showing nothing in the end.

The folder structure it should be looping through is:

```
jekyll
|
 --faqs
   |
   --name-of-faq
   --name-of-faq-2
```

Sample markdown file:

```
title: name of faq
faq_id: 2567
slug: title-of-faq
created: Mar 6, 2017
modified: Mar 6, 2017
faq_category: how to fly
```

Comment: `faq` or `faqs` are collections? What does those key/values pairs looks like? an example of that file would be helpful along its full path.

Comment: `faqs` is the folder name. I've updated the question with a sample of a faq markdown file.

Comment: The site structure is setup to be that all faqs are under the faqs folder. I can access them with `site.faqs` in a for loop, so this should work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `site.faqs` use `site.posts` to get an array of posts.

Then put the markdown files in the folder: `/faqs/_posts/` for example: `/faqs/_posts/faq1.md`.

After that you should be able to browse them like:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
{{post.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

To filter a specific category use: `site.categories.CATEGORY` or filter them like: (for example the category "mycategory")

```
<ul>
{% for post in site.faqs %} 
{% if post.categories contains "mycategory" %}
 <li>{{ post.title }}</li> 
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried `{% for post in site.categories.name-of-category %}
          <ul>
            <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
          </ul>
          {% endfor %}` but this isn't building correctly. I have a folder `_faqs` with a long list of `.md` files. Each file contains a `faq_category` key and value that I'm trying to display faq's by. I believe this should use a where clause, but can't get it to work.

Comment: Why do you use `_faqs` instead of `faqs`?

Comment: The project was setup with all folders under jekyll folder having a prefix of "_". That shouldn't matter.

Comment: In fact, it matters.

Comment: I can loop through the _faqs folder and get a list of all of the posts with 
`{% for post in site.faqs %}
          <ul>
            <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
          </ul>
          {% endfor %}`, so how do I filter them and only display the posts with a specific category from the faq_category key?